# When trying to add extension to selenium, I get "Parameter 'self' unfilled."

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, self

I'm trying to create something in Python that will just add an extension to Chrome on runtime using selenium.

My code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver

Options = webdriver.ChromeOptions
Options.add_extension(extension="./extension.crx")
#                                                ^
#                                               parameter self unfilled
#
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="./chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=Options)
driver.get("https://google.com")
driver.quit()
quit()
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `webdriver.ChromeOptions` is the class itself, not an instance. You need `webdriver.ChromeOptions()`. I'm marking this as a typo.

Comment: Thanks! I should have noticed that. It worked.

Please put that as an answer so I can mark it as the solution.